# Why does "diezmar" have a diphthong, and do similar verbs exist?

Tags: etimología, verbos, fonología, diptongos

### Backstory

*Diezmar* is a more modern version of *dezmar*, meaning "to decimate".

Many verbs undergo diphthongization in their conjugations when [stressed syllables fall on historic vowels](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/20696/20700) `/ɛ/` `/ɔ/` from Latin. e.g.

- *p**e**nsar* > *p**ie**nso*
- *p**o**der* > *p**ue**do*

But I can think of no other examples where this diphthongization carries on into the (unstressed position) in the infinitive (and thus *all* conjugated forms).

The *RAE* [claims](http://dle.rae.es/?id=DitQLZk) the addition of the diphthong is due to the influence of (the noun) *diezmo*:

> #### [diezmar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=DitQLZk)
>
> De *dezmar*, **por infl. de *diezmo*.**

---

### Question

**Are there any other examples of verbs which have changed their form under the influence of a noun cognate?** And if not, why did it happen with this verb? e.g.

- *dezmar* > *d**ie**zmar* (por inf. de *d**ie**zmo*)
- *pensar* > **p**ie**nsar* (por inf. de [*p**ie**nso*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SxBPv3A|SxCsyei))
- *contar* > **c**ue**ntar* (por inf. de *c**ue**nto*)

<sup>**Note:** I am not looking for instances of verbs which have diphthongs due to the Latin root having two neighbouring vowels e.g. *or**ie**ntar* from Latin [*or**iē**ns*](https://www.scribd.com/document/158436269/Diccionario-Critico-Etimologico-castellano-MI-RI-Corominas-Joan-pdf).</sup>

---

<sup>Etymological history of relevant terms:</sup>

[image]

<sup>[Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=diezmar%2Cdezmar&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=21) comparison of *diezmar* (earliest e.g. 1728) and *dezmar* (earliest e.g. 1610).</sup>

Comment: both *amoblar* and *amueblar* exist, in a similar process I imagine.

Comment: I would say most of what you can find will be covered by {noun + *-ear*} or {*a-* + noun + *-ar*}.

Comment: It's not exactly the same thing (*vowel raising* vs *diphthongs*) but they also maintain an unexpected infinitive stem (when it 'should' change from *-e-* to *-i-*, following the 'rules' of diphthongizing *-ir* verbs) due to them being more recent versions of classically *-er* verbs: http://spanishlinguist.us/2017/12/irregular-irregulars/

The rest are just other verbs which have alternative sets of conjugations/alternative spellings of the infinitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Diezmar* has a diphthong because of *diezmo*, as the DLE says.

This could have happened by [backformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-formation) and re-derivation: once you have *diezmo*, you remove the suffix *-o* that makes it a regular masculine noun and then add *-ar* to turn it into a verb. There's another verb that means the same, but the speakers don't like the fact that it has another root and forget it in favor of the one they've created.

Or it could be because of analogy: *dezmar* has several very common obviously related words and they all have a diphthong, so the verb changes to match the rest of the family. The noun *diezmo* was probably more common than the verb, and it was "backed up" by the extremely common numeral *diez* (and *dieciséis, diecisiete, dieciocho, diecinueve*). The only other form of this historical root that doesn't have the diphthong when stressed is *décimo*, but it is a bit technical and not nearly as common as the numerals.

In general one would expect that "irregular" vowel-alternating verbs would become regularized, as [has happened in a few verbs](https://www.staff.ncl.ac.uk/i.e.mackenzie/hisverbr.htm) like *prestar* and *entregar* (whose Latin roots had lax /ɛ/ and which had forms like *priesto* and *entriego* in Old Spanish).

There are however a few cases of regular verbs (with a Latin root in /e/) that actually took the other way and diphthongized, like *sembrar* and *colar*.

If you loosen the requirements a bit, you can find a lot of newer verbs that have a diphthong in all forms (that is, they don't alternate). However that's not because they've shifted from older alternating forms but because they were derived from nouns where the Latin root had a short (later lax) vowel which then turned into a diphthong. Since Spanish noun inflection never shifts the stress, nouns don't alternate vowels, so if a noun acquired the diphthong, it stayed there in every word that was derived from it.

So we have e. g. *puente* from Latin *pŏntis*, but the modern verb that means "to go over sthg./sbdy.; to make a direct connection in a circuit" is *puentear*, because it was formed on modern *[puente](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UZtOEos)* + *[-ear](http://dle.rae.es/?id=EIeaLdH)*. In the same way there is *fiestear* < *fiesta* < Latin *fĕsta* (but *festejar* "to party, to celebrate* keeps the monophthong /e/ in the first syllable), and *afiebrarse* < *fiebre* < L. *fĕbris* (but we also have the somewhat cultured *febril*), and *[cuerdear](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BaVzijF)* < *cuerda* < L. *chŏrda* (but also *cordón* and *cordaje*).

Answer (score 1):

## Influence of verb forms

This additionally happened with *adestrar, amoblar, desosar*:

> Less frequently, the diphthong forms prevailed, producing the following modern regular verbs (with diphthongs in all 47 conjugations): <sup>25</sup>
>
> [image]
>
> ...
>
> <sup>25 For each of these verbs, the “old” (mixed diphthong pattern) forms still exist but are rarely used: *adestrar, dezmar, amoblar, desosar.*</sup>
>
> - [*Spanish Verbs made Simple(r)*](http://the-eye.eu/public/WorldTracker.org/Language%20Learning/18.Spanish%2C%20Catalan%20and%20Basque/12.Spanish%20Verbs%20Made%20Simple%28r%29.pdf) (p.44)

And also with the Old Spanish verb *levar* > **lievar* > [*llevar*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/llevar#Etymology_2):

> The shift of an initial 'l' to 'll' is not normal, but is explained by the fact that in Medieval/Old Spanish, the third-person present indicative was *lieva*, which was then altered into *lleva*; eventually this was extended to the entire verb.<sup>1</sup>
>
> ...
>
> <sup>1. *Diccionario Crítico Etimológico Castellano* (G-MA), Joan Corominas</sup>
>
> ---
>
> [image]
>
> - [*A History of the Spanish Language*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?redir_esc=y&id=ZjcrhyQlFa0C) (p.184)

---

## Influence of nouns

There are many more examples of this happening under influence of a cognate noun with diphthongization:

**e > ie**

- *atesar, [atiesar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4EDbG5L)*
- *beldar, [bieldar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5TiruGu)* (dialectal)
- *relevar, [relievar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Vq8iY8l)* (*Bol., Col., Ec. y Perú*)
- *festejar, fiestear*
- *aneblar, [anieblar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=2gRJgn4)*
- *despezar, [despiezar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=DM6Fz6R)* (Architecture and Engineering)
- *enmerdar, [enmierdar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=FWd8Xaf)*
- *desherbar, [deshierbar/desyerbar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=D42gTlf)*
- *alebrestarse, [aliebrestarse](http://dle.rae.es/?id=1qabY1j)*
- *-, afiebrarse*

**o > ue**

- *[pontear](http://dle.rae.es/?id=TeHEvwQ), puentear*
- *cordelar, cuerdear*

**Elision**

- *encrudelecer, [encruelecer](http://dle.rae.es/?id=FAK5GiX)* (*cruel*)

---

**Similar phenomena:**

<sup>• *cerner/cernir, hender/hendir*</sup>
<sup>• *ergir* (*yer-/ir-*), [Spanish Verbs Made Simple(r) - By David Brodsky](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=bUW7fa6oCb4C&pg=PA278&dq=alternative) (Search *"alternative"*)</sup>
<sup>• [Past participle doublets](http://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-verbs-with-double-participles-spanish.html)</sup>
<sup>• **Vowel heightening (o > u):** [*podrir, pudrir*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/27134/del-origen-y-usos-de-los-verbos-podrir-pudrir-en-espa%C3%B1a); [*jogar, jugar*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/30351/is-jugar-the-only-u-to-ue-stem-changing-verb/30352); *troncar, truncar*; *torrar, turrar*; *tollir, tullir*; *tollecer, tullecer*; *noroestear, [noruestear](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QdM5AJ7)* (*norueste*)</sup>