# Del origen y usos de los verbos podrir/pudrir en España

Tags: verbos, historia, españa, vocales

Según [la RAE](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=podrir) en España es de uso actual el verbo *pudrir* con U, siendo en América coexistentes las formas *podrir* y *pudrir*. Además ambas son existentes desde tiempo atrás (desde el español medieval). Si bien la etimología (el latino *putrēre*) daría a pensar que primero fue la forma con u, no falta el término que en latín se escribe con u y en español tiene o (de *cum* viene con) ¿Cuál de los verbos sería el original (Se remitiría a cual está escrito primero, pues no contamos con otros registros)? ¿Se usa el verbo (aunque en forma vulgar) en dialecto alguno de la península con O? ¿Por qué y desde cuando se redujo o desapareció el verbo *podrir* en España?

Comment: Tal vez por su ambigüedad con Podría y Pudría

Comment: La [respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/27151/14627) de @ukemi da en el clavo. De hecho a una palabra latina con *u* corta como *putrēre* le corresponde regularmente una *o* en castellano, de manera que *podrir* es la forma esperada y *pudrir* la irregular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Podrir* es la forma más antigua. *Pudrir* aparece circa 1500 según el CORDE, mientras que *podrir* se usa desde los documentos registrados más tempranos de los fines del siglo XIII.

Mi suposición es que, dado que hay ["vowel raising"](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/2751/vowel-harmony-in-spanish) on [en la mayoría de las formas conjugadas de *podrir*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=TUQkmyv), estas formas influyeron el desarrollo de *pudrir* en el cual la *u* vocal aparece en cada conjugación, similar al caso con [*dezmar > diezmar*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/23615/why-does-diezmar-have-a-diphthong-and-do-similar-verbs-exist).

i.e.

- putrere   → *putrīre  → podrir   → pudrir <sup>(por inf. de *pudro, pudres, pudre, ... pudriendo* etc)</sup>
- /puˈtre.re/ → [poˈtri.re] → /poˈðɾiɾ/ → /puˈðɾiɾ/

Según [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=podrir%2C+pudrir&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=21&smoothing=3), *pudrir* comenzó a superar *podrir* en popularidad a principios de los 90.